# How long is it safe to keep sausage?

Tags: food-safety, meat

I bought a one-pound tube of pork sausage. After opening it, and putting it in a zip-lock bag (weeks before the sell-by date), the remainder turned gray on the outside the next day. I understand that turning gray is normal and does not necessarily mean that meat has gone bad. I am not confident in my ability to identify meat that has gone bad by smell.

When should I throw it away? Should I just cook it all at once, and keep the cooked product if I don't want to eat it all? (I trust cooked food in the fridge for a longer time than it is likely to take me to eat all of it, so this is a viable possibility, but inconvenient.) Should I be splitting it into smaller portions and freezing it?

Comment: [Try this](http://www.stilltasty.com/searchitems/search/sausage)

Comment: Are we talking about fresh breakfast sausage?

Comment: @Jolenealaska Yes.